# How can I create a cross-product object with names from a list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, datatable, cartesian-product

I have an in-memory representation of a list of some n data columns

```
Dim l As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Double)))
```

For example

```
Column 1: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Column 2: {-0.05, 0, 450.7}
etc.
```

I need to cross join, take the Cartesian product of, or whatever nomenclature you prefer, the entire list, retain the names, and store the result into an object.  The result would look like

```
 Col 1   Col 2
 1       -0.05
 1        0
 1        450.7
 2       -0.05
 2        0
 2        450.7
 3       -0.05
(etc.)
```

How can this be done?

Update:

The below answer works in C#.  For posterity here's a VB.Net equivalent (due credit to the author)

```
    Private Function CartesianProduct(Of T)(sequences As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim result As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)) = {Enumerable.Empty(Of T)}
        For Each sequence In sequences
            Dim s = sequence
            result = From seq In result
                     From item In s
                     Select seq.Concat({item})
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using a [**`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than a list of key/value pairs?

Comment: It would be easy enough to rewrite it as a Dictionary, but I'm unsure how a Dictionary would make it easier to get the cross product of the values.

Comment: Perhaps _that_ part isn't easier, but what is better is tgat dictionaries provide hash-based lookup (note: does not allow duplicates) which makes accessing items faster in cases where the key is known. Ex. if you are to get the item for the name `Column 1` you'd only need one line: `myDictionary("Column 1")` whereas for your list you would have to iterate it until you find the name.

Comment: Though it is completely up to you and your needs. I just thought it was a bit strange to almost replicate the behaviour of a dictionary using a list. Though the list provides index-based lookup which is perhaps needed in your case. -- Well what do I know? Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: Yeah I was messing around with a few ways including using indices and just used that part as a visual example to describe the preconditions for my main objective.  I can see though how your comment would help for people who aren't familiar with a Dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
Dim c1 = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim c2 = New List(Of Double) From {-0.05, 0, 450.7}
Dim product = From first In c1 From second In c2 Select New With {first, second}

For Each x In product
    Console.WriteLine(x)
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

If you need to get the cartesian product of more than 2 columns, here is a an article of Eric Lippert on this subject (C#): [Computing a Cartesian product with LINQ](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

I am using an [Anonymous Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types), [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Yes, I need a solution like the one he mentions wherein the number of columns isn't known at compile-time.

Comment: Also that solution is actually not far from what I had attempted, but the syntax had eluded me.